# Android hide listview scrollbar?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

Is there a way to hide scrollbar in `ListView`. I know it's possible for `ScrollView` but can't find a way for `ListView` scrollbar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Try to type this in layout xml file

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Tutorial is here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was expectiogn something like setScrollBarEnabled or something like that.

Comment: For future reference: setVertical/HorizontalScrollBarEnabled/Disabled()

Comment: Hi all, I want to hide scrollbar in listview. here your mention line for getting this work but I didn't catchup where can I write this line, I am working on xamarn forms.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to disable \ enable scrollbars **programmatically** you need use

[View.setVericalScrollbarEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(boolean)) - disable \ enable **vertical** scrollbars.

[View.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(boolean)) - disable \ enable **horizontal** scrollbars.

Answer (score 8):

This is the property you should use on your `ListView`. All the best.

`android:scrollbars="none"`

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that fast scrolling disabled:

```
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
```

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Usually using both of them

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```