# How to customise listview scrollbar so it cannot be clicked.?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have `ListView` with `ScrollBar` enabled in Android.

I dont want the user to click on the `ScrollBar` and drag it.

How to customise ListView's ScrollBar so it cannot be clicked.?

Comment: disable fastScroll using list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrollbar of ListView should be made outside using

yourlistview.setScrollBarStyle(ListView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);

Make a LinearLayout above the ScrollBar with transparent background and consume its touch .

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scroll_bar"
                android:layout_width="5dp"                 // ScrollBar widthh
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.scroll_bar);

 ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can make to scrollbar to be visible but still not clickable. A workaround will be just to hide the scrollbar and the user will not be able to click it. [Android hide listview scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062072/android-hide-listview-scrollbar)