# How to remove hybrid app "grey" bar?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to remove the grey bar when the content is shorter than the height of display?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug, try the ionic forum http://forum.ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belonging to this answer: [Android hide listview scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7062180/3671726) i would recommend you to set `android:scrollbars="none"` into your `layout.xml`. A Guide with detailed information about that can be found here: [Android - Hide Scrollbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars)

If that doesn't help, try to add this into your `stylesheet.css`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```