# hide scrollbar shape in android textview

Tags: android

i have a text view in my activity that populate from database . but when it's big Scrollbar shape show override the text . this is screenshot from it :

[image]

This is the textView xml :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMatn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dark_line"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

now I want hide the ScrollBar shape

Comment: remove line android:scrollbars="vertical".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android hide listview scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062072/android-hide-listview-scrollbar)

Comment: i voted to close this question because it is basically a duplicate of various similar questions dating back many years AND it also shows very little research effort.  `android:scrollbars="none"`  I DID NOT DOWNVOTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
enter code here
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">
 <TextView
  here your text
  />
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i think . this shape appear with scrollview too . am i right ?

Comment: android:scrollbars="none"
you can use this

Comment: your textview is inside ScrollView ?

Answer (score 4):

maybe you enable scrollability of textview by

```
1. in java code : TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
2. in xml : android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

... but only first job enable scrollability text without second job

so answer is below

```
1. in java code : TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
2. in xml : android:scrollbars="none"
```

delta is value of android:scrollbars vertical->none

Comment: Why answer a duplicated question?

Comment: Your answers is perfectly working for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
```

Keep the scroll Set transparent

Answer (score 1):

In XML

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or in Kotlin Class

```
editText?.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
```

In Java Class

Answer (score 0):

implemented the OnTouchListener inside the adapter and set it on the text view he logic for touch event is: I check if the touch event is a tap or a swipe

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mIsScrolling = false;
        mDownX = motionEvent.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float deltaX = mDownX - motionEvent.getX();
        if ((Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop)) { // swipe detected
            mIsScrolling = true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (!mIsScrolling) {
            openNewScreen(v); // this method is used for click listener of the ListView
        }
        break;

}

return false;
 }
```